# Unexpected '.' in Twig/Extension/Core.php after deployment

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-3.2

I have tried to run my Symfony application on a remote server.

For this I chose cloud9, temporarily.

Unfortunately, for some reasons I can't get the page to work.

After loading the files and running `composer install`, which works fine (apart from one warning:

> Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in
>   composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to
>   update them.

And attempting to call my */web* folder I get this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.' in
>   /home/ubuntu/workspace/Centaur/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php

Which points to this line of code

```
$ret = $object->$method(...$arguments);
```

---

The app worked perfectly on my local drive.

Locally I have Windows 10 with **PHP 7.0.9**
On cloud9 the system is linux, and I have installed **PHP 7.0.20**

In `composer.json` twig is called out like this `"twig/twig": "^2.0"`

Using symfony 3.2.

I have honestly ran out of ideas to save this. If anyone has any idea about how to fix this, please let me know!

Comment: Are you sure the host is running that version of `PHP`? Did you verify with `phpinfo()`?

Comment: Splat operator (...) was added in PHP 5.6, so it looks like you're not really using PHP 7.0.20. You should verify that. Note that you may have a few PHP versions on your server, and webserver may use a different version than you can access via CLI with `php` command.

Comment: Running phpinfo shows that it's using php 5.x. I will try to change it now